# Remove class on body does not work with pagepiling.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagepiling.js

I've made a website using [pagepiling.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js), this script adds the class 'active' on the section which is in the viewport. Now I want add a class on my body when my `section1` is `active` like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#section1').hasClass("active") === true) {
        $('body').toggleClass("one");
    }
});
```

It is working well (the class is added on the body) but when I scroll my `section1` does not have the class `active` because I am now on `section2`, the class on the body is not removed. How can I fix it? I also tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#section1').hasClass('active')) {
        $('body').addClass('one');
    }
    else {
        $('body').removeClass('one');
    }
});
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Did you just downvoted my answer? Can I ask why?

Comment: In any case, I'm wondering how can you accept an answer that doesn't even work... the scroll event is not even being propagated when using pagePiling.js... And I'm telling you this as the creator of the plugin...

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your condition inside scroll event because you should check every time the user scroll :

```
$('body').on('scroll', function() {
    if ( $('#section1').hasClass("active") ){
        $('body').toggleClass("one");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not the way to do it.... [IT DOESN'T EVEN WORK](http://jsfiddle.net/hrrLvd2a/31/) because pagePiling.js doesn't fire the scroll event. You should be using the pagePiling.js callbacks, or as I suggested in my answer, use the class pagePling.js adds for you.
**Definitely this should not be the accepted answer.**

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want add a class on my body when my section1 is active

You actually don't need to.

PagePiling.js adds a class to the `body` element for you with the form `pp-viewing-page2`. You can check it in your DOM inspector in the [demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/#page2).

But if you still want to add a class, just use the callbacks the plugin provides, like this:

```
$('#pagepiling').pagepiling({
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        if(index == 1){
            $('body').addClass('one');
        }else{
            $('body').removeClass('one');
        }           
    }
});
```